I'm trying to select an item from listbox1 and replace the values in textbox1 accordingly
This is just a sample code for people who will try to do something similar.
Is an example of the code:
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
   string strok = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   string name = strok.Split(' ')[0];
   var selgrah = name.ToLower();
   textBox1.Text = selgrah;
}


And? Try having a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

This is a Q&A site specifically. Are you asking a question or are you trying to provide a tip? There are sites where that's OK but this is not one of them.

I dont really see what do u exactly want to achieve, but as I understood, you want to set the Text of your textbox when clicking on a item of your ListBox.
You can use the SelectedIndexChanged event of your ListBox to change the text each time you click on an item.
Here is what i did :
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strok = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string name = strok.Split(' ')[0];
    var selgrah = name.ToLower();
    textBox1.Text = selgrah;     
}

Here you can find events associated with your control
And my result: 
